# How to comparison between register with arrays and numbers

Tags: c++

```
typedef struct {
int codigo;
char Nombre[MAX_NAME];
char Especie[MAX_ESP];
char tipo;
int voto;
bool controles[MAX_CONTROLES];
int num_controles;
}TAnimal;



TAnimal zoo[500];

if (zoo[i].controles == 1){
```

`controles` is boolean, so my error is

```
ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
```

So, how can i compare that?

Comment: There's not enough here to know what's going on.  Please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hint: `zoo[i].controles` is not boolean.

Comment: Ya i know that, but how can I compare that? :S

Comment: Gwaaaarrnnn.. show us the declaration for 'zoo'.. :)

Comment: @Seokjin We'd need to know what the type of controles is obviously

Comment: zoo, zoo, zoo, typedef for you, you, you.. ?

Comment: `Controles` is boolean!

Comment: No it isn't, just show us the declaration. We can't help you if you keep being so stubborn.

Comment: I was editing sorry!

Comment: `zoo[i].controles[ ??? ]` is boolean (after you replace ??? with something appropriate). But `zoo[i].controles` is an array (decays to a pointer in most contexts).

Comment: `controles` is an array of booleans, so you should specify an index, then it's a boolean : `zoo[i].controles[i]`.

Comment: omg thank youu fixed up! thanks a lot

Comment: @zenith, That comment was when he had not edited. Deleted that now. :)

Answer (score 3):

`controles[]` is not `bool`, it is an `array of bool`.

```
bool controles[MAX_CONTROLES];
```

---

When you use it like this

```
if (zoo[i].controles == 1){
```

Using the base address of the array, makes it to decay to a pointer, Hence the error

```
ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
```

---

Depending on your requirement, I would guess that you are trying to compare with one of the elements in that array `controles[]`. And to access that element you need to provide the index of that element in place of `x` in the below line

```
if (zoo[i].controles[ x ] == 1){
```

Comment: Hence the error message about "comparison between pointer ..." - an array decays to a pointer.

Comment: @WeatherVane, were you suggesting me to add that? Cause I have.

Comment: Just agreeing really with a +1.

Comment: In C++, a `bool` has two possible values: `true` or `false`. Comparing a `bool` to 1 is not idiomatic. Indeed, I'd say that comparing a `bool` is not idiomatic, since a `bool` is, well, boolean, just like the condition expression in the `if`; `if (zoo[i].controles[x]) ... `